# WCSession in Glance Interface (Watch OS 2.0)

Tags: ios, watchkit, watchos-2

I'm trying to use messaging (part of the new WatchConnectivity introduced in watchOS 2.0) in my glance. In my glance controller I have.

```
-(void)willActivate {
    [super willActivate];

    if ([WCSession isSupported]) {
        WCSession *session = [WCSession defaultSession];
        session.delegate = self;
        [session activateSession];
    }

}
```

This works in the main interface albeit takes a good few seconds to actually become reachable in the simulator.  I monitor the reachability by checking `sessionReachabilityDidChange:`.  However only in my glance interface it never becomes reachable. Without it being reachable I cannot retrieve data from the phone. Has anyone run into this? Maybe it's just a simulator issue.  I'm using xCode 7 Beta 5.

Thanks!

Comment: I am using Xcode Beta 6 with iOS 9 and WatchOS2 beta 5.  I too have seen this behavior in both the simulator and the on the watch for Glance interfaces.  The phone is not reachable (session.reachable) and the WCSessionDelegate sessionReachabilityDidChange is never called. I'm not sure if this is just a bug or if WCSession is not supported in Glance interfaces(?) I guess I'll search through the forums and bug reports to confirm.  If anyone has any insights into this matter, please feel free to comment.

Comment: did you get a solution on this ?

Answer (score 2):

There is *only one* shared WCSession object and it has only one delegate, so setting it twice in the app's init/willActivate and then in the Glance init/willActivate will cause issues.

The viable way is to set it in WKExtensionDelegate's init method

```
class ExtensionDelegate: WKExtensionDelegate, WCSessionDelegate{

   let TAG : String = "ExtensionDelegate: "
   let session = WCSession.defaultSession()

   override init () {
       super.init()

       println("\(TAG) - init")
       println("\(TAG)Setting delegate and Activating WCSession.defaultSession()...")

       session.delegate = self
       session.activateSession()
   }

   .
   .
   .
}
```

Comment: Hey Mithil , i dont know how true that is, remember the glance does not call the extension delegate , only the main app, so if they go into the glance first, there will be no WCsession started. Let me know if im incorrect.

Comment: I experimented with keeping a reference to the session object (there's only one shared session so that's fine), and then tried setting the delegate in both the ExtensionDelegate's willBecomeActive method, and also in the Glance's didActivate method. This way, when either one is about to be on screen they will assume the role of the delegate. But there's a bug transitioning from the Glance to the app which I've raised with Apple; the session reports unreachable after you tap on the Glance. But fine if you exit the glance to the watch face then enter the app manually. Odd!

Comment: @user3099837 Extension delegate is called by the Glance as well as Complication, Notification along with the watchOS app. You can try using the above code which I mentioned and using the Glance scheme in Xcode. Just that "WatchKit delivers *life cycle events* to your extension delegate only when your Watch app runs". But note that init () of ExtensionDelegate is called whenever any part of of watchOS app runs. Do try it and let me know. I have my Glance and app working fine.

Comment: This one caught me too. A Glance has a `WKExtension` and `WKExtensionDelegate` object but the usual lifecycle events ("didFinishLaunching" etc) aren't called when the Glance is run. If you're depending on those methods to do setup it won't happen for a Glance launch. That's why you need to use the `WKExtensionDelegate` `init()` method to set up the session.

Answer (score 1):

Before your session will have became reachable, you can communicate with `updateApplicationContext:`.

So you can check in your iOS side that the watch is reachable, and if not then use updateApplicationContext: to set some application context data which will be available for the watch when the user start using your watchkit app. Or even in the glance you can use this context data.

When your willActivate method will get called, you can set the WCSession delegate, and activate the session. When the session will be activated, then it will call your session:didReceiveApplicationContext: callback with the previously set appcontext data. After this, you can use the sendMessage because in this point your watch is reachable.
Note that the updateApplicationContext method is not called on the main thread.

In the other direction, you can wake up your iOS app in the background with using the sendMessage method from the watch. This means you have to setup the WCSession in your appdelegate on the iOS side.

Reachable state needs that both the iOS app and the watch app (or glance) are running.

For more info check the WWDC Session 713: Introducing Watch Connectivity